# Add Buy Me A Coffee Widget to React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a component that renders the [Buy Me A Coffee](https://www.buymeacoffee.com) widget in some routes of my react single page application. This is my component so far:

```
class BuyMeACoffee extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount () {
         const script = document.createElement("script",);
         script.setAttribute('data-name','BMC-Widget')
         script.src = "https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js"
         script.setAttribute('data-id', 'boulderproblems');
         script.setAttribute('data-description', 'Thank you for your support!');
         script.setAttribute('data-message', 'This web is free to use. Do you want to help supporting it?');
         script.setAttribute('data-color',"#FF5F5F")
         script.setAttribute('data-position','right')
         script.setAttribute('data-x_margin','18')
         script.setAttribute('data-y-margin','18')
         script.async = true
         document.head.appendChild(script)
    }

    render(){
         return(null)
    }
}
```

When I inspect the page with the developer tools, the  tag is at the end of the head section and everything seems correct but the widget doesn't show in the page.

Note: If I copy the script code in the head section of the index.html page:

```
<script data-name="BMC-Widget" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="boulderproblems" data-description="Thank you for your support!" data-message="This web is free to use. Do you want to help supporting it?" data-color="#FF5F5F" data-position="right" data-x_margin="18" data-y-margin="18"></script>
```

then it works perfectly. The problem is that in this case, the widget is shown for all routes. I have also tried react-helmet without success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finnally got it working. I post my solution here in case it is useful for someone. Not sure if it is the most elegant but it works. I slightly modified the original component so the script and widget is removed when the component is unmounted. Here is the component now:

```js
class BuyMeACoffe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute('data-name','BMC-Widget')
        script.src = "https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js"
        script.setAttribute('data-id', 'boulderproblems');
        script.setAttribute('data-description', 'Thank you for your support!');
        script.setAttribute('data-message', 'This web is free to use. Do you want to help supporting it?');
        script.setAttribute('data-color',"#FF5F5F")
        script.setAttribute('data-position','right')
        script.setAttribute('data-x_margin','18')
        script.setAttribute('data-y-margin','18')
        script.async = true
        //Call window on load to show the image
        script.onload=function(){
            var evt = document.createEvent('Event');  
            evt.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', false, false);  
            window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        this.script=script
    }

    componentDidMount () {    
        document.head.appendChild(this.script)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.head.removeChild(this.script);
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("bmc-wbtn"))
     }

    render(){
        return(null)
    }
}
```

Basically, after reading the buymeacoffee script I realized that they load the widget when the window is DOMContentLoaded event is fired. What I do is to fire this event manually after I insert the script.

Note: After doing this, I had to add a couple of styles because the widget was showing out of the screen. Maybe it was because of my layout. Anyway, here they are in case they you need them:

```
#bmc-wbtn{
    bottom: 15px;
}

#bmc-wbtn + div{
    bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: how to do this on funcitonal component?

Comment: the one statement of ` script.onload=function(){
            var evt = document.createEvent('Event');  
            evt.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', false, false);  
            window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }`   worked for me

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way. 
You can create a react component like this.

Coffee.js

```
function Coffee() {
return (
<a
  className="buyButton"
  target="_blank"
  href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/theshubhagrwl"
>
  <img
    className="coffeeImage"
    src="https://cdn.buymeacoffee.com/buttons/bmc-new-btn-logo.svg"
    alt="Buy me a coffee"
  />
  <span className="coffeeButtonText">Buy me a coffee</span>
</a>
 );
}
```

Styles.css

```
.buyButton {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff813f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
  font-family: cursive;
}
.buyButton:hover,
.buyButton:active,
.buyButton:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 2px rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.85;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.coffeeImage {
  height: 2vh;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.coffeeButtonText {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will give you easy customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the copied ***code*** provided by *buymecoffee.com* into **head** tag of your **index.html** of your React project. It will load automatically onLoad of your React App. You can customize the properties inside it if required, But I think you don't need to create a separate component to make it work.
You can find your index.html inside the public folder.

> project-name > public > index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>

    <script
      data-name="BMC-Widget"
      data-cfasync="false"
      src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js"
      data-id="codesim"
      data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!"
      data-message=""
      data-color=""
      data-position="Right"
      data-x_margin="18"
      data-y_margin="18"
    ></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed, we sometimes forget that React.js is part of a simple html page. So adding it outside the root div like we did in the old days, is still an option :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Widget you can embed that in iframe

```
const BuyMeACoffeeWidget = () => {
  const path = "https://www.buymeacoffee.com/widget/page/PskV9Rt?description=Support%20me%20on%20Buy%20me%20a%20coffee!&color=%235F7FFF";

  return (
    <iframe className="bmc" src={path} />
  );
};
export default BuyMeACoffeeWidget;
```

Add custom styling

```
.bmc{
  height: 100%;    
  border: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

And use in your repo where required

```
<BuyMeACoffeeWidget />
```

Also in case if you wanna add the redirection Image to your application, just put the image in Public/image folder and use the path in imag source tag in code.

[image]

I took a snip it of the image, put this in image folder and used this in code like

```
const BuyMeACoffeeSupport = () => {
    return (
       
      <a href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/PskV9Rt">
        <img src="img/bmc.PNG" />
      </a>
       
    );
}
export default BuyMeACoffeeSupport;
```

And use in your repo where required

```
<BuyMeACoffeeSupport/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is for functional component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Buymeacoffee() {
  // const
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const div = document.getElementById("supportByBMC");
    script.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js"
    );
    script.setAttribute("data-name", "BMC-Widget");
    script.setAttribute("data-cfasync", "false");
    script.setAttribute("data-id", "algorithammer");
    script.setAttribute("data-description", "Support me on Buy me a coffee!");
    script.setAttribute(
      "data-message",
      "Buying a single coffee for me is 1000 times worth than a Thankyou "
    );
    script.setAttribute("data-color", "#5F7FFF");
    script.setAttribute("data-position", "Right");
    script.setAttribute("data-x_margin", "18");
    script.setAttribute("data-y_margin", "18");

    script.onload = function () {
      var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
      evt.initEvent("DOMContentLoaded", false, false);
      window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    };

    div.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  return <div id="supportByBMC"></div>;
}
```

```
.supportFromHome {
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

output :is at the bottom of the page:
[image]