# How to embed a <script> widget in next.js only on a certain page?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to load an external script which embedds the "Buy Me A Coffee" widget onto a site. I am unable to get the script to execute unless I place the script in the `_app.js` file. But by adding the script to the `_app.js` file the widget is loaded on every page. I only want it loaded on a single page so I tried added the script to the head of the page I would like it loaded on:

```
<Head>
// Some content
  <Script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="some-id" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#5F7FFF" data-position="Right" data-x_margin="18" data-y_margin="18"/>
</Head>
```

that did not work and the docs say to add `Script` tags outside of the `Head` tags so I moved the script outside of the head tag like so:

```
<Head>
// Some content
</Head>
<Script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="some-id" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#5F7FFF" data-position="Right" data-x_margin="18" data-y_margin="18"/>
```

But that still did not work. The widget is just not loading on the site unless I put the script into the `_app.js` file.

I've read the documentation on the `Script` and `Head` tags for next.js but that is not helping out with this. I could definitely use some help with getting this to work.

Comment: Have you try adding `strategy="beforeInteractive"` prop to `Script` component.

Comment: I have, and I've tried the other two loading strategies as well. I'm not sure if it matters but the page I am trying to implement this widget on is behind a login page

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this is how you add a third-party script in next.js.

```
<Head>
// Some content
</Head>
<Script
    strategy="afterInteractive"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
      (function (d, s, id) {
              var js,
                el = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
              }
              js = d.createElement(s);
              js.async = true;
              js.src = "https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js";
              js.id = id;
              js.charset = "UTF-8";
              el.parentNode.insertBefore(js, el);
      })(document, "script", "buymeacoffee-js");
    `,
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The buymeacoffee script loads the widget when the window is DOMContentLoaded event is fired (as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039217/add-buy-me-a-coffee-widget-to-react-application)). So you can use @dpacman's answer along with a content strategy of 'beforeInteractive'